# Android: My service doesn't want to start

Tags: android

I have: `<service android:name=".kernel.background.Process"></service>`
Main package is:  `package="call.com"`

I want to create a process which will start sync method for my database, for now I found some example, but..

this is my background process:

```
package call.com.kernel.background;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class Process extends Service {

private final Timer timer   = new Timer();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    
    super.onCreate();
    
    startservice();
    
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private void startservice() {
    
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            
            System.out.println("time:");
            System.out.println("is:");
            System.out.println("up:");
            
        }
        
    }, 0, 1000);

    ;
}

private void stopservice() {
    
    if(timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
    }
    
}

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please post the output of Logcat.

Comment: I don't get error, i just put breakpoints, and i see that i never go to this service. // I have point on: onCreate and inside of the timer, and i do not see anything like System.out.print..

Comment: How are you calling this service?
Are you using an intent or starting from at the root of your application?

Comment: Note that Android ignores breakpoints while debugging when you don't set the debuggable flag in your manifest to true. (just in case you are not aware)

Answer (score 1):

Where are you calling `startService(...)` from? An `Activity` somewhere in your code would need to be starting your service. Have you read the [Android Service Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) yet? They give a lot of insight as to how to properly build and start a service.

If your breakpoint is in the `run()` method of your `TimerTask` and it isn't being hit, then it definitely sounds like the service has never been called:

So from your `Activity`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Process.class);
startService(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are starting is a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). You are starting a timer. You could use a separate [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) to do your update operations. Here is a link to a good article called [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html). Please see the referenced links to learn more about each.